# how set the same width of the div and of image

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want to create a responsive site in which i used a full of images and when i put a mouse on image it a flat color div appears with same width as image. Right now i did this with fixed width but I want to do responsive i.e if I re size browser or for different resolutions the image changes its dimensions but div element would not.

The code is like this

```
<div id="thumbs-cont">
  <div class="thumbnails">
  <img src="images/armin_vit_secrethandshake-325x325.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="thumb-name"> aaa aa</div>
  <div class="thumb-desc"> ab ab ab</div>
  <div class="thumbnails">
  <img src="images/armin_vit_secrethandshake-325x325.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="thumb-name"> aaa aa</div>
  <div class="thumb-desc"> ab ab ab</div>
  <div class="thumbnails">
  <img src="images/armin_vit_secrethandshake-325x325.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="thumb-name"> aaa aa</div>
  <div class="thumb-desc"> ab ab ab</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make your question a bit clearer? Maybe use a JSFiddle or a few images to show what you want because your description isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I Think with `flexbox` you can solve problem.

Read This:

http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, what you are trying to achieve is a grid of images, each image on mouse reveals some info in form of a div. Look at this tutorial with downloadable project files, might solve your problem.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/responsive-full-width-grid/

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick here is to set the parent elements position to relative that way you can set the width of the image to 100%;

```
.thumbnails {
     position:relative;
}
.thumbnails img {
       width: 100%;
       height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on hover of a image, you can do something like below:

```
$('divId').height($(this).height());
$('divId').width($(this).width());
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/nDU3G/) (*resize and check*)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you correctly position your :hover activated div as absolute in relation to it's parent, you can simply set it's width and height at 100% and it's always going to have the good size.

Try resizing the preview window from left to right. You'll notice that the hover div adapts it's size to it's parent.